# How remove from and To in eml file

Tags: vb.net, email, eml

I create a eml file from MailMessage and `SMTPdeliverymethod.specifiedpickupdirectory`

But To save it, I need to fill TO and FROM field. But In fact I don't need them.
Is It possible to save mailMeassge without them?
Or I try to create a new eml file like [here](https://www.dcaric.com/blog/generating-draft-eml-files-from-asp-net-mvc)

```
dim sr as new io.streamreader(Path)
dim sw as new streamwriter(io.Path.combine(io.path.getdirectoryname(Path),"modified.eml")
dim line as string= sr.readline
while line <> nothing
   if not line.startswith("X-Sender:") andalso line.startswith("X-Receiver:") Andalso line.startswith("From:") andalso line.startswith("To:") thensw.writeline(line)
   line=sr.readline
end while
sw.flush
sw.close
```

But my new file isn't full. I lost my attachments and others lines

How can I have an eml file without from and To. When I want to open, I can fill myself. Or About From field : is it possible to say to take default account of outlook, when user click on it?

Comment: A tip if u wan to parse the eml in c# : Just add empty string in the `To` and `From` field and save it as a `.mht` file than rather then a `.eml` file.Then u can easily use the `WebBrowser` control to read the `.mht` file

Comment: Can you save an attachment in mht file???

Comment: not sure but u can save it separately easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's cause by error in while loop in source webSite

```
while not sr.enfofstream
    dim line as string=sr.readline
    if not ....
end while
```

It's good now.